# ListView array adapter input edittext Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, alarmmanager

I've written a code for an android app, that can input times and generate alarm on that.
Initially, I've added two buttons for input time and a button to `set alarm`.
Now, I want to refine my approach i.e want to remove the  set alarm button and the time set buttons to input time in text form rather than `TimePicker`.
For that sake, I wrote a code for `ListView Array Adapter`, so that I can input only two times and the input times to store in that array `Adapter` for alarm service. But unfortunately, have to face a-lot of difficulties. Now What changes should I make in my **code/approach** to refine that in a better way. 
 **My Simple Code:**

```
package com.task;

        import java.util.Calendar;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlarmManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TimePicker;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            Calendar Alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
            Button  b1,b2;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
                b1.setOnClickListener(this);
                b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
                b2.setOnClickListener(this);
                Button alrm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.alrm);
                alrm.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View clickedView) {
                if ((clickedView.getId() == R.id.b1) ||
                        (clickedView.getId() == R.id.b2)
                        {
    TimePickerDialog t= new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
                t.show();
                }
                else if (clickedView.getId() == R.id.alrm) 
                    {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recv.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0); // Unique value for every Alarm
                Alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                am.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }

            }

            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
                    Alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
                    Alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                }
            };
        }
```

**My ListView Code (try):**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        for (int x=0; x<=2; x++) // loop for iterating array members
        {
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                               
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                edit.setText("");               
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: You did not tell what changes you made. Nor did you tell which difficulties you encountered.

Comment: I'm implementing as different project. I'm facing difficulties in restricting Adapter size not greater than 2, although I used `list.size()`

Comment: Very good to start another project. But still you could tell which changes you made. Before you had two buttons. And now? And what is the size of an adapter? And why do you you want to restrict it?

Comment: I want to restrict the adapter size to 2 buttons input only. now I have a text area, were I want to input the time instead of button.

Comment: What is exactly a `text area`? Sorry, but can't you describe what you do or have changed or what you want to do more to the point?

Comment: @greenapps I'm sorry for that. The text area means the EditText area of the time input, not for the time picker.

Comment: One EditText? But don't you want to input two times? I asked what you changed all and the difficulties you have. I will not ask again.

Comment: one editText means the first I enter the first time, and that will store in the Adapter, then I add second by clicking on the same edit text to add another one. @greenapps

Comment: I wonder why you are not able to tell to the point what you want to implement. Had a look at your code now. Better remove line   `for (int x=0; x<=2; x++) // loop for iterating array members` as that makes no sense. After that try again and tell which probkems you have.

Comment: @greenapps removed. Now how to limit the AdapterArray.size() to 2, i.e that should only add 2 values in the List.

Comment: Instead of limiting adaptersize you could simply make the EditText invisible as soon as list.size() becomes 2.

Comment: I tried `list.size()` but its always true, i.e taking no restriction. can u provide me a abstract code of it, by editing my post?

Comment: I will not do that. Instead you edit your post and add the code you tried. list.size() returns an integer so how come you say it is always true?